# How to make this operator call unambiguous?

Tags: c++, pointers, operator-overloading, smart-pointers, implicit-conversion

I'm writing a smart pointer as my school assignment, and I've ran into a problem. A conversion between my smart pointer and a raw pointer is needed, so I implemented it with operator overloading into my smart pointer class like this:

```
operator T*() {
    return raw_pointer;
}
```

Another requirement is to implement the == operator, which should work between smart pointers and between smart pointers and raw pointers as well. 
I've implemented it like this, this overloading can also be found in my smart pointer class:

```
bool operator== (const smart_pointer<T> &smart_pointer) {
    return raw_pointer == smart_pointer.raw_pointer;
}
```

Now, when I try to do something like this:

```
smart_pointer<obj> sp = new obj();
obj *p = new obj();
if(sp == p) {
    // do something
else {
    // do something else
}
```

I get the following error message:

```
ambiguous overload for 'operator=='
candidates are:
operator==(obj*, obj*) <built-in>
bool smart_pointer<T>::operator==(const smart_pointer<T>&) [with T = obj]
```

I guess it does not know if it should use the built in one and convert my smart pointer to a raw pointer, or should it use my method that is overloading the == operator. The thing is I currently cannot think of anything to solve this situation. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implicit conversions between raw pointers and smart pointers are kinda dangerous, which is why the standard smart pointers don't provide them. It would be best if you simply didn't have them.

That said, that may not be your choice. The solution to your actual problem is to simply add more overloads of the equals operator, for mixed comparisons between smart pointers and raw pointers. Those will then be preferred over those that need conversions in either direction.

Answer (score 1):

Setting your constructor or conversion `explicit` should solve the ambiguity:

```
explicit smart_pointer(T*);
```

or

```
explicit operator T*() const {
    return raw_pointer;
}
```

Create the multiple overloads is an other alternative/complement.

As pointed in comment, you don't want the constructor to be implicit for a premature destruction of pointer.

It would be better that the conversion is also explicit, and then adding overloads for the different combinaison

Comment: If this smart pointer is about ownership (as most smart pointers are) then you would not want a comparison with a raw pointer to destroy that raw pointer's pointed to object, would you? I guess with that hint you can figure out which one of the two suggestions is rather ungood. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Creating overloads of comparison operators etc. for every possible combination of argument types is not practical.

Making the conversion to raw pointer `explicit` can be a good thing in itself, but does not solve this problem. The ambiguity would be resolved, so that the code compiled, but at the cost of creating a temporary smart pointer for the raw pointer. At the end of the full-expression that smart pointer's destructor would destroy the poor raw pointer's referent.

So the general solution is to make every single-argument constructor `explicit`, or else add (non-defaulted) formal arguments.